# Django pass model to widget in ModelForm

Tags: python, django, modelform

I have a `ModelForm` that has an extra field that is a custom widget. I can add an extra field with a widget and pass arbitrary key values to it when constructing the widget. I'm also able to access model data within the `ModelForm` in the `__init__` function.

My problem lies in that adding an extra field in the `ModelForm` requires doing so outside the `__init__` function while accessing model data is only possible from within the `__init__` function.

```
class SomeForm(forms.ModelForm):
        title = None
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
                some_data = kwargs['instance'].some_data
                # ^ Here I can access model data.
                super(SomeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
                self.fields['some_extra_field'] = forms.CharField(widget= SomWidget())
                # ^ This is where I would pass model data, but this does not add the field.
        class Meta:
                model = Page 
                fields = "__all__"
        some_extra_field = forms.CharField(widget= SomeWidget())
        # ^ I can add a field here, but there's no way to pass some_data to it.
```

I've also tried setting `self.some_data` in `__init__`, but it's still not accessible when I try to use `self.some_data` when setting `some_extra_field` at then end of the class.

How should pass model data to a widget in a `ModelForm`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm following what you need correctly, you can do this simply by editing or reassigning the widget in `__init__`. Something like:

```
class SomeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    title = None
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        some_data = kwargs['instance'].some_data
        super(SomeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # Pass whatever data you want to the widget constructor here
        self.fields['some_extra_field'].widget = SomWidget(foo=...))
        # or possibly (depending on what you're doing)
        self.fields['some_extra_field'].widget.foo = ...
```

Comment: Firstly, thank you. Since `some_extra_field` is not in the model, trying to assign a `.widget` to the array results in a key error. Could this be a versioning thing?

Comment: Well, you still need to declare the field - if the only thing that's unusual about it is that you want to adjust the widget based on the arguments to `__init__`, declaring it as you did in your example (outside `__init__`) should be sufficient. If you always plan to reassign the widget, it doesn't matter what widget you use in the declaration - leaving it at the default should be fine. If you might not have a model instance (say in a create view) you should use whatever widget you want for that case.

Comment: Creating a new field in the `__init__` method and inserting it into `self.fields` is normal too, but not necessary if all you want to do with it is tweak the widget.